# How to keep a custom map visible during a regular google maps search?

Tags: google-maps, google-my-maps

I have a custom map saved. On the computer, I view it by going to `[Hamburger Icon] > Your places > Maps`. When I click on the map, I can see the places on that map. But I want to search hotels near some of those places, and I can't figure out how. When I hit the back arrow, the map disappears. How can I keep my custom map visible during a normal Goole maps search? Surely this has to be possible...